# Not able to edit Record type of child object by clicking edit button from related list

Tags: record-type, related-list, relationships

I was trying to edit the record type of Related Contact from Account detail page, by going to the Contacts related List and clicking on the "Edit" button.
The field is editable , but for some reasons, the layout which came up didn't allow me to update the record type.

However, when I clicked on Contact Name to open it in a new tab, I was able to change the record type.

Is it something that Salesforce doesn't allow its user to do?
Please tell.

Comment: Which layout came, could you please provide snapshot? Were there any errors or record type change link was missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Recordtype can only be changed fro the detail page if the record type field is visible or when creating the record.

If you are on the **edit** page and record type is visible it will only show the current value and **not** let you edit it

If you are on the **detail** page and the record type field is visible there will be a "*Change*" link next to the record type **if you have record types available, other than the current record type, for your profile**